# How do I display a lightbox on only homepage of my blogger blog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have this code:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'/>

     <script src='https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/[www.gj37765.blogspot.com]jquery.colorbox-min.js'/>
 <link href='https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/%5Bwww.gj37765.blogspot.com%5Dfbpopup.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (document.cookie.indexOf(&#39;visited=flase&#39;) == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = &quot;visited=false;expires=&quot; + expires.toUTCString();
        $.colorbox({width:&quot;400px&quot;, inline:true, href:&quot;#mdfb&quot;});
            }
     });
     </script>
```

The code is for a Facebook-like box which appears when a user visits my blog. My blog is on blogger. My problem is that the lightbox of this jquery appears again and again whenever a user sees other posts or refreshes the page. I want it to appear only on the home page of site. I don't know anything about jQuery.

Comment: Help us out here ... you need to be more descriptive, and provide some specific information:
For example: when you say " this jquery appears again and again" do you mean the specific code is appearing, or that you are seeing multiple lightbox?
Where is this code? Is it in the template for all of your pages? if so, that is why it appears on all pages, and not just the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Likely its all the `&quot;`. Change all of them to `"`. Change `&39;` to `'` as well

Comment: And the `&#39;` literal - change that to `'`

Comment: I tried but it didnt worked. I can see the lightbox again when i move to next page.

Comment: are you including it in a template?

Comment: Yes . In my blogger template . I just want that lightbox to appear only once when a user visits on homepage of site. but Its appearing on everypage .

Comment: You should post it on your home page not the template.

Comment: @chakram88 ... I mean the lightbox appears on every page after refreshing. I just want it to display on homepage of my blogger blog.